# How to Make the Predicate in WHERE Clause Optional Based on a Parameter

Tags: sql, oracle11g, where-clause, optional-parameters

I have a SQL that needs to execute  with or without a condition/predicate in the WHERE clause. This predicate happens to be a subquery that needs to be included in the `WHERE` clause if certain value is passed onto the PL/SQL stored proc:

```
SELECT /* several columns */
FROM X JOIN Y ON X.A = Y.A
WHERE COL1 = 'a'
  AND COL2 IS NULL
  AND /* Several other predicates */
  AND /* This condition should be included only if a value of parameter is 'G'. If it is 'H', it should NOT consider this condition at all */
     NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Z WHERE Z.A = X.A)
```

I tried to use a CASE/WHEN/THEN/ELSE but I can't get the 'H' option working, e.g.:

```
SELECT /* several columns */
FROM X JOIN Y ON X.A = Y.A
WHERE COL1 = 'a'
  AND COL2 IS NULL
  AND (CASE
           WHEN 'G' = P_SP_PARAM AND
               NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                           FROM Z
                           WHERE Z.A = X.A)
           THEN 1
           WHEN 'H' = P_SP_PARAM 
           THEN 0
        ELSE 0
        END) = 1
```

Comment: I think you got it backwards. If H is the default then should return 1 so the condition return true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
AND
(P_SP_PARAM <> 'G' OR
 NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Z WHERE Z.A = X.A)
)
```

If you specifically want it to `H`, then:

```
AND
(P_SP_PARAM = 'H' OR
 NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Z WHERE Z.A = X.A)
)
```

Both these versions assume `P_SP_PARAM` is not `NULL`.  The logically can easily be modified to take this into account.

Comment: I might have not gotten my question correctly across, but the goal is just to execute the NOT EXISTS (subquery) if the parameter is 'G'. In that case, we can exclude the second part (for 'H') entirely. With that said, it seems like your solution will work.

Comment: @NuCradle . . . The first version handles the `= 'G'` case.

Comment: I see. I thought you are saying both conditions should be added (not being mutually exclusive). Thanks.